# Incremental file changes lost when pushing commit to github

Tags: git, github

I made a change to my local repository and when I compare my changes (using Visual Studio) I can see the incremental changes to the file.  However, when I push the commit to github and then view the file diff in my online repository, it shows the entire file (in red) and then the entire file with my changes (in green).  In other words, it should just show the additions in green.

Any ideas on why this is happening?  I don't have this issue with other repositories.

Comment: I would bet that your diff tool marks the line different if the line ending is not the same, and that the local copy uses windows EOLs (\r\n) whereas the github repo stores them as unix EOLs (\n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Scott Hanselman wrote it, **[You're just another carriage return line feed in the wall](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YoureJustAnotherCarriageReturnLineFeedInTheWall.aspx)**.

Basicaly, your local (ie. workdir) line endings do not match your repository ones. You most certainly work on Windows and your lines ends with a CRLF, whereas your git repository is configured to store text files with LF line endings.

Some useful resources to help you understand and fix this:

- Tim Clem's awesome post **["Mind the End of Your Line"](http://timclem.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)**
- GitHub help **[page on this topic](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)**

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set your line ending manipulation to be switched off:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

You should also tell git to not highlight the CR character (`^M`) at the end of the line with:

```
git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```